# Is there a better way to write this loop? Maybe with streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to learn how to use streams better, and I thought this bit of code might be better with streams.

```
List<Integer> origList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();

//Need at least a first and a last
if(origList.size < 2) {
    return newList;
}

//Add First
newList.add(origList.get(0));

//Play leap frog and only add ever other item in the middle
for(int i = 1; i < origList.size() - 1; i++) {
    if(i%2 == 1) {
        newList.add(origList.get(i));
    }
}

//Add Last
newList.add(origList.get(origList.size-1));

System.out.println(newList); // expect: [1,2,4,6]
```

Comment: Purely as an exercise in streams, you could do that by implementing your own [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html). You could then use it like this: `List<Integer> newList = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6).collect(new MyCollector())`

Comment: Have you tried using streams? Where did you get stuck? How do you measure whether it's "better"?

Comment: Well, streams should be stateless. While you could implement this with a collector (and streams), I do not recommended.it for (stream) beginners.

Answer (score 1):

I’d stay with the loop. But instead of iterating over all numbers, just to skip every second with a modulo test, iterate over every 2nd number in the first place:

```
newList.add(origList.get(0));
int last = origList.size() - 1;
for(int i = 1; i < last; i += 2) newList.add(origList.get(i));
newList.add(origList.get(last));
```

You may use a stream

```
List<Integer> newList = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(0),
    IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(0, last / 2).map(i -> i * 2 + 1), IntStream.of(last)))
        .mapToObj(origList::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it’s not necessarily an improvement over the loop version…

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do it with a custom collector. But the collector is not really nice. Anyway, here you go:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

public class MyCollector<T> implements Collector<T, MyCollector.DataHolder<T>, List<T>> {

    static class DataHolder<T> {
        T first;
        T last;
        List<T> evens = new LinkedList<>();
        List<T> odds = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean hasFirst = false;
        boolean hasLast = false;
        boolean even = true;

        void accummulate(T next) {
            if (!hasFirst) {
                hasFirst = true;
                first = next;
                return;
            }
            if (!hasLast) {
                hasLast = true;
                last = next;
                return;
            }
            T cur = last;
            last = next;
            if (even) {
                evens.add(cur);
            } else {
                odds.add(cur);
            }
            even = !even;
        }

        DataHolder<T> combine(DataHolder<T> other) {
            if (!hasFirst)
                return other;
            if (hasLast) {
                if (even) {
                    evens.add(last);
                    odds.add(other.first);
                    evens.addAll(other.evens);
                    odds.addAll(other.odds);
                    last = other.last;
                    even = other.even;
                } else {
                    odds.add(last);
                    evens.add(other.first);
                    odds.addAll(other.evens);
                    evens.addAll(other.odds);
                    last = other.last;
                    even = !other.even;
                }
            } else {
                if (even) {
                    evens.add(other.first);
                    odds.addAll(other.evens);
                    evens.addAll(other.odds);
                    last = other.last;
                    even = !other.even;
                } else {
                    odds.add(other.first);
                    evens.addAll(other.evens);
                    odds.addAll(other.odds);
                    last = other.last;
                    even = other.even;
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        List<T> finish() {
            if (hasFirst)
                evens.add(0, first);
            if (hasLast)
                evens.add(last);
            return evens;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<DataHolder<T>> supplier() {
        return DataHolder::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<DataHolder<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return DataHolder::accummulate;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<DataHolder<T>> combiner() {
        return DataHolder::combine;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<DataHolder<T>, List<T>> finisher() {
        return DataHolder::finish;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    // Test main, just to show off.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).stream().collect(new MyCollector<>()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference an *effectively final* (constant reference) counter:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
List<Integer> newList = origList.stream()
        .filter(x -> count.getAndIncrement() % 2 == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
newList.add(0, origList.get(0));
Optional.of(origList.size()).filter(n -> n % 2 == 1).ifPresent(n -> newList.add(origList.get(n - 1)));
```

This code produces the desired output given the sample input.

Comment: `filter()` should be stateless. This will fail in parallel.

Comment: Well, it's not [Stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness). Will break if you add a `parallel()` and a few more items.

Comment: Also, `toList()` doesn't promise to return a mutable list.

Comment: But you can easily avoid both problems: `IntStream.range(0, origList.size()).filter(x -> x % 2 == 1).mapToObj(origList::get).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))`

Comment: @shmosel you raise some good points. This doesn't use a parellel streams and `toList()` in practice does return a mutable list (unit testing would pick this up if that changes), so they are not an issue IMHO. I like your `IntStream` idea. Although it seems less "streamy" to me, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: The spec doesn't differentiate between parallel and sequential streams. `toList()` may return a mutable list in your testing, but that could vary by implementation, version, or execution.

Comment: Tested your implementation with `parallelStream()` and as input the numbers from 1 to 1000. Did not produce the right result.

Comment: And unit testing will currently pick up a lot `getClass().getClassLoader() instanceof URLClassLoader`.